# How to detect focused UITextField in Container view from Parent View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, segue, container-view

I have a container view with multiple text boxes on it. I also have a button in Parent View controller(custom keypad). What I'm trying to do is select text box first & when I tap on the button I wanted some value to be populated to that last selected/focused textbox.
How can I do that? any alternative ways are welcome too. (I am having multiple container-views in the original code and try to use one keypad for all the views)

[image: storyboard]

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    var weightVC : WeightViewController!
    var focusedElement : UITextField

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "weight") {
            weightVC = segue.destination as? WeightViewController
        }
    }

    @IBAction func button1Clicked(_ sender: Any) {

        if weightVC != nil {
            weightVC.sampleTextBox1.text = "1"
            //I want this sampleTextBox1 to be dynamic like weightVC.focusedInput = "1"
        }

    }
}

extension MainViewController:ChildToParentProtocol {
   func setFocusedElement(with value: UITextField){
      focusedElement = value
   }
}
```

Container View Controller

```
protocol ChildToParentProtocol: class {
    func setFocusedElement(with value:UITextField)
}

class WeightViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate:  ChildToParentProtocol? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var sampleTextBox1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var sampleTextBox2: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // sampleTextBox1 Editing Did Begin event
    @IBAction func editBeginSampleText1(_ sender: Any) {
        print("edit begin")
        delegate?.setFocusedElement(with: sampleTextBox1)
    }

}
```

In other words, I simply want to keep a reference to last focused UITextFild when a button is tapped. Hope my requirement is clear enough. Please guide me if there is a way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you can keep track on which `UITextField` is tapped by using it's tag. And you can use `UITextFieldDelegate` to get the selected `UITextField` tag.

Consider the below code for `WeightViewController`

```
protocol ChildToParentProtocol: class {
    //Changed value to Int for passing the tag.
    func setFocusedElement(with value: Int)
}

import UIKit

class WeightViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tf1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tf2: UITextField!

    var selectedTFTag = 0
    weak var delegate: ChildToParentProtocol? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Assign delegate and tags to your TF
        tf1.delegate = self
        tf2.delegate = self

        tf1.tag = 1
        tf2.tag = 2
    }
}

extension WeightViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //Get the selected TF tag
        selectedTFTag = textField.tag
        //Pass tag to parent view
        delegate?.setFocusedElement(with: selectedTFTag)
    }
}
```

Now in your parent view `ViewController` you need to make some modification. I have added comments where I made changes to achieve your requirement.

```
import UIKit

//You need to confirm your ChildToParentProtocol with your UIViewController
class ViewController: UIViewController, ChildToParentProtocol {

    var selectedTFTag = 0
    var weightVC : WeightViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "weight" {
            weightVC = segue.destination as? WeightViewController
            //You need to pass delegate to containerview to make it working.
            weightVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btn1Tapped(_ sender: Any) {

        //According to selected Tag perform your action
        if selectedTFTag > 0 {
            switch selectedTFTag {
            case 1:
                //set up first UITextField
                weightVC.tf1.text = "First textfield was selected"
                print("1")
            case 2:
                //set up second UITextField
                weightVC.tf2.text = "Second textfield was selected"
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func btn2Tapped(_ sender: Any) {

        //According to selected Tag perform your action
        if selectedTFTag > 0 {
            switch selectedTFTag {
            case 1:
                //set up first UITextField
                weightVC.tf1.text = "First textfield was selected"
                print("1")
            case 2:
                //set up second UITextField
                weightVC.tf2.text = "Second textfield was selected"
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func setFocusedElement(with value: Int) {
        //Get selected TF tag with delegate
        selectedTFTag = value
    }
}
```

You can check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=67635481488896260064) demo project for more info.